# Count unique lines only to a set pattern

Tags: awk, grep, sort, uniq, batch-jobs

How can I count the unique log lines in a text file only until the first "-" and print the line with the count

```
org.springframework. - initialization started
org.springframework. - initialization started
pushAttemptLogger - initialization started
pushAttemptLogger - initialization started
```

example result

```
org.springframework. 2
pushAttemptLogger 2
```

reviewed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712437/find-duplicate-lines-in-a-file-and-count-how-many-time-each-line-was-duplicated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cut -f1 -d'-' inputfile | sort | uniq -c`

`cut -f1 -d'-'` will treat the file as dash-delimited and return only the first column in each line.

`sort` is necessary for `uniq` to work properly.

`uniq -c` shows only unique lines from the sorted input, including a count.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk -F- 'NF>1 {count[$1]++}
         END {for (i in count) print i, count[i]}'
```